# After setting an administrator password while installing XP I cannot log in?

Tags: windows-xp, administrator

When I setup my new computer, I put in an administrator password when it asked me to.  After the system reboots, my password doesn't work and I cannot log in at all? I also cannot get it to start up in safe mode to try and log in that way. What can I do now?

Comment: Check CAPSlock (it might have been on when you typed the password the first time). If you are on a laptop: same for numlock. If both of those fail: Either restore from backup or use a tools to reset the password.  (e.g. ERD commander 2005 and the locksmith option, or this iso (burn to CD, boot from CD) http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

Comment: F8 does not work for safe mode? Your keyboard working? try a different keyboard, wired if you can.

Comment: I don't want t give unnecesary answers, so after chack caps lock, are you determining definitely bad entered password and are interested in a way to reset it?

Comment: Make sure the keyboard layout during setup is the same as on the login screen. You might try switching to other likely layouts depending on your chosen regional settings.

Answer (score 1):

The most possible answer of your problem is to enter the password in caps lock on mode (because you may have entered your password on caps lock mode), check your keyboards all the keys are working properly.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions!  I checked caps lock, tried the keys next to the ones that I used for the PW, brand new wired keyboard that works other than letting me use safe mode to start.

Comment: It is a new out of the factory box computer (from HP) so I would like to be able to access in ANY way!  Is there a way to reset it; not worried about losing any info as I have nothing on it yet.

Comment: if you are 100% sure that your keyboard and everything is working fine and you still want to use same windows then you have to reset your administrator account. I have done this many times but you have to do little work i.e. go to this link http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/ create bootable cd, run it and follow the instructin.